# Filter data from Postgres db through tkinter GUI

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter

I am a novice at programming but I am building an accounting software for my friends Salon cause I saw his receptionist was keeping records with pen and paper.

I am having troubles filtering data if who ever is using the software wants to filter employees by day or month or year or just dates without considering the employees.

After building the GUI, I have assigned a command to the 'search' button:

```
def search():

    r_r_treeview()
    if sem.get() == "" and day_input.get() == "" and month_input.get() == "" and year_input.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror('Empty field',
                             "All fields cannot be empty")
        refresh()

    else:
        for rows in db.search_entry(sem.get(), day_input.get(), month_input.get(), year_input.get()):
            db_id = rows[0]
            db_employee = rows[1]
            db_service = rows[2]
            db_day = rows[3]
            db_month = rows[4]
            db_year = rows[5]
            db_time = rows[6]
            db_amount = rows[7]

            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=db_id, text=db_id,
                           values=(db_employee, db_service, db_day, db_month, db_year, db_time, db_amount))

            search_employee_name.delete(0, END)
            day_entry.delete(0, END)
            month_entry.delete(0, END)
            year_entry.delete(0, END)

            get_total()
```

(sem is the input field for employee name under 'search display here', day, month and year follows)

This is what I have written to get the results from a Postgres db:

```
def search_entry(employee='%', day='%', month='%', year='%'):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='afro' user='postgres' password='xxxx' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cutentry WHERE employee LIKE %s AND day LIKE %s AND month LIKE %s AND year LIKE %s",
                (employee, day, month, year))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

This is an image of the GUI:
[image]

I want the user to be able to enter one or more parameters (i.e either employee alone or employee and another condition like day or month or year).

Currently it does not return any rows.

If you would like to get hands on the whole project to help me out, I can provide a Github link too. Thank you

Comment: You should probably try understanding what `and` and `or` is, and use them accordingly. And use `print()` to verify if the values you get are what you expect itself.

Comment: I used a OR before, but then even if I provide two parameters, it only considers one. My thought is I need a condition for when any of the entries are empty.

Comment: Yes, also check your sql query.

Comment: I can't find my way around it, I'll appreciate an answer or correction please, thank you

Comment: Use `print(rows)` to verify that and use `print()` on all the input from entry widget to confirm its values, then you can figure it out from then on.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to sleep on it and came up with a solution that works for me. it may not be very efficient if you are trying to filter a lot of columns but here is what I did.

I defined multiple functions to query my db;

```
def search_entry_employee_byday(employee='%', day='%', month='%', year='%'):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='afro' user='postgres' password='xxxx' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cutentry WHERE employee LIKE %s AND day LIKE %s AND month LIKE %s AND year LIKE %s",
                (employee, day, month, year))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows


def search_entry_employee_bymonth(employee='%', month='%', year='%'):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='afro' user='postgres' password='xxxx' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cutentry WHERE employee LIKE %s AND month LIKE %s AND year LIKE %s",
                (employee, month, year))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows


def search_entry_employee_byyear(employee='%', year='%'):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='afro' user='postgres' password='xxxx' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cutentry WHERE employee LIKE %s AND year LIKE %s",
                (employee, year))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows


def search_entry_all_byday(day='%', month='%', year='%'):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='afro' user='postgres' password='xxxx' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cutentry WHERE day LIKE %s AND month LIKE %s AND year LIKE %s",
                (day, month, year))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows


def search_entry_all_bymonth(month='%', year='%'):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='afro' user='postgres' password='xxxx' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cutentry WHERE month LIKE %s AND year LIKE %s",
                (month, year))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows


def search_entry_all_byyear(year):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='afro' user='postgres' password='xxxx' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cutentry WHERE year = %s", (year,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows


def search_entry_employee_byall(employee):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='afro' user='postgres' password='xxxx' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cutentry WHERE employee = %s", (employee,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

Then I split my search function into multiple conditions:

```
def search():
    global employee
    global day
    global month
    global year

    r_r_treeview()
    if sem.get() == "" and day_input.get() == "" and month_input.get() == "" and year_input.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror('Empty field',
                             "All fields cannot be empty")
        refresh()

    else:
        if sem.get() != "" and day_input.get() != "" and month_input.get() != "" and year_input.get() != "":

            for rows in db.search_entry_employee_byday(employee=sem.get(),
                                                       day=day_input.get(),
                                                       month=month_input.get(),
                                                       year=year_input.get()):
                db_id = rows[0]
                db_employee = rows[1]
                db_service = rows[2]
                db_day = rows[3]
                db_month = rows[4]
                db_year = rows[5]
                db_time = rows[6]
                db_amount = rows[7]

                my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=db_id, text=db_id,
                               values=(db_employee, db_service, db_day, db_month, db_year, db_time, db_amount))

                search_employee_name.delete(0, END)
                day_entry.delete(0, END)
                month_entry.delete(0, END)
                year_entry.delete(0, END)

                get_total()
        else:
            pass

        if sem.get() != "" and day_input.get() == "" and month_input.get() != "" and year_input.get() != "":

            for rows in db.search_entry_employee_bymonth(employee=sem.get(),
                                                         month=month_input.get(),
                                                         year=year_input.get()):
                db_id = rows[0]
                db_employee = rows[1]
                db_service = rows[2]
                db_day = rows[3]
                db_month = rows[4]
                db_year = rows[5]
                db_time = rows[6]
                db_amount = rows[7]

                my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=db_id, text=db_id,
                               values=(db_employee, db_service, db_day, db_month, db_year, db_time, db_amount))

                search_employee_name.delete(0, END)
                day_entry.delete(0, END)
                month_entry.delete(0, END)
                year_entry.delete(0, END)

                get_total()
        else:
            pass

        if sem.get() != "" and day_input.get() == "" and month_input.get() == "" and year_input.get() != "":

            for rows in db.search_entry_employee_byyear(employee=sem.get(),
                                                        year=year_input.get()):
                db_id = rows[0]
                db_employee = rows[1]
                db_service = rows[2]
                db_day = rows[3]
                db_month = rows[4]
                db_year = rows[5]
                db_time = rows[6]
                db_amount = rows[7]

                my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=db_id, text=db_id,
                               values=(db_employee, db_service, db_day, db_month, db_year, db_time, db_amount))

                search_employee_name.delete(0, END)
                day_entry.delete(0, END)
                month_entry.delete(0, END)
                year_entry.delete(0, END)

                get_total()
        else:
            pass

        if sem.get() == "" and day_input.get() != "" and month_input.get() != "" and year_input.get() != "":

            for rows in db.search_entry_all_byday(day=day_input.get(),
                                                  month=month_input.get(),
                                                  year=year_input.get()):
                db_id = rows[0]
                db_employee = rows[1]
                db_service = rows[2]
                db_day = rows[3]
                db_month = rows[4]
                db_year = rows[5]
                db_time = rows[6]
                db_amount = rows[7]

                my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=db_id, text=db_id,
                               values=(db_employee, db_service, db_day, db_month, db_year, db_time, db_amount))

                search_employee_name.delete(0, END)
                day_entry.delete(0, END)
                month_entry.delete(0, END)
                year_entry.delete(0, END)

                get_total()
        else:
            pass

        if sem.get() == "" and day_input.get() == "" and month_input.get() != "" and year_input.get() != "":

            for rows in db.search_entry_all_bymonth(
                    month=month_input.get(),
                    year=year_input.get()):
                db_id = rows[0]
                db_employee = rows[1]
                db_service = rows[2]
                db_day = rows[3]
                db_month = rows[4]
                db_year = rows[5]
                db_time = rows[6]
                db_amount = rows[7]

                my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=db_id, text=db_id,
                               values=(db_employee, db_service, db_day, db_month, db_year, db_time, db_amount))

                search_employee_name.delete(0, END)
                day_entry.delete(0, END)
                month_entry.delete(0, END)
                year_entry.delete(0, END)

                get_total()
        else:
            pass

        if sem.get() == "" and day_input.get() == "" and month_input.get() == "" and year_input.get() != "":

            for rows in db.search_entry_all_byyear(year_input.get()):
                db_id = rows[0]
                db_employee = rows[1]
                db_service = rows[2]
                db_day = rows[3]
                db_month = rows[4]
                db_year = rows[5]
                db_time = rows[6]
                db_amount = rows[7]

                my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=db_id, text=db_id,
                               values=(db_employee, db_service, db_day, db_month, db_year, db_time, db_amount))

                search_employee_name.delete(0, END)
                day_entry.delete(0, END)
                month_entry.delete(0, END)
                year_entry.delete(0, END)

                get_total()
        else:
            pass

        if sem.get() != "" and day_input.get() == "" and month_input.get() == "" and year_input.get() == "":

            for rows in db.search_entry_employee_byall(sem.get()):
                db_id = rows[0]
                db_employee = rows[1]
                db_service = rows[2]
                db_day = rows[3]
                db_month = rows[4]
                db_year = rows[5]
                db_time = rows[6]
                db_amount = rows[7]

                my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=db_id, text=db_id,
                               values=(db_employee, db_service, db_day, db_month, db_year, db_time, db_amount))

                search_employee_name.delete(0, END)
                day_entry.delete(0, END)
                month_entry.delete(0, END)
                year_entry.delete(0, END)

                get_total()
        else:
            pass
```